# What are the possible use cases in Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, use-case

I would like to know the possible use cases of Amazon RDS ?

How can we leverage the features and services of amazon RDS?

What is the master slave relationship in RDS? how can we implement this??

Answer (score 1):

You should start here to learn more about Amazon RDS: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/rds/

Comment: I have read the documentation a little bit but i am still not clear. Means what can be the case scenarios where i can use this RDS. I have imported the database on rds now how can i implement the master slave relationship in rds

Answer (score 1):

You can use RDS in the same use cases you would use the supported relational databases, currently MySQL, Postgres, Oracle and SQL Server, but without installing and managing it yourself.

The master-slave replication feature is called "Multi-AZ" and you can enable when creating your database instances.